# Merging columns (h2o.merge) using H2O in SparkR

Tags: r, merge, sparkr, h2o

In my current project, I am using H2O machine learning library in SparkR. I have multiple .csv files and reading these .csv files through h2o data frame. Now, I would like to apply `h2o.merge()` function over the files to **map primary key of one h2o data frame with the foreign key of another h2o data frame**. My main h2o data frame contains 14 columns. I get data types of all the columns using `h2o.getTypes()` function.

In order to apply `h2o.merge()` function, the column should be of type string or numeric instead of enum or real. So to convert data type of columns, I am using `h2o.ascharacter()` and `h2o.asfactor()` functions. Now, I have converted enum columns to string columns to use `h2o.merge()` functions. When I used `h2o.merge()` function it displays following error:
[image: SparkR console] 
Am I missing anything ? I have captured the syntax to use `h2o.merge()` function from this link [Syntax of h2o.merge function](https://rdrr.io/cran/h2o/man/h2o.merge.html).
How to merge h2o data frames?
Sample data set of factTable h2o data frame is shown below **(SALES_ORG is a primary key)**:
[image: sample factTable data set]
Sample data set of regionTable h2o data frame is shown below **(SALES_ORG is a foreign key)**:
[image: Sample regionTable data set]

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example (including sample data)?

Comment: what is the key from the both tables? i think you need to defined. How can executer found similarity between two tables without key value???

Comment: @sahildesai: The key is defined between both tables. I am mapping only key columns in the merge operation.

Comment: I've often found that I have to convert strings to factors before merging to get h2o.merge to work correctly.  I wonder if you are encountering something similar here.

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp- Can you please post this as an answer. The hidden logic is column should be in enum/ factor format to perform merge operation using h2o. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: You may try `by.x = regionTable[,1]` and `by.y = factTable[,5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figure out the answers using the hint from the comment. **The basic thing is we need to convert column into factor/enum before applying merge operation**. The data type of the column having either primary key or foreign key should be factor/enum.